# Powershell import exported files

Tags: active-directory, powershell-ise

I need to update expiration date for multiple users based on email addresses. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get this working so right now I'm converting firstly email address to samAccountname and after setting the validity date based on the samAccountName. Unfrotunately I don't really know how to connect these two codes together into one script. Could you please advise how should I connect them? Thank you.

```
Import-Module activedirectory
$users = Get-Content C:\Scripts\test.txt
$users | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "samAccountName -eq '$_'" -properties samaccountname | Select samaccountname
} | Export-CSV C:\Scripts\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8



Import-CSV  "C:\Scripts\test.csv" | ForEach-Object {
$usr = get-aduser $_.samAccountName  |Select samAccountName  
Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $usr.samAccountName  -DateTime '21/09/2018' -Verbose
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood what your are trying to achieve, You have CSV files with users emails and expiration date. and you want to use this info to update the users expiration date.

Lets assume that you have the following headers in the CSV, "User Email" and  "User expiration date". so when you import the CSV file to a variable, you will have a PS custom object with the information. lets say that we use the $Users variable.

```
PS C:\> $users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\users.csv

PS C:\> $users

User Email             User expiration date
----------             --------------------
contact@saggiehaim.net 24/09/2018          
info@saggiehaim.net    20/09/2018          
admin@saggiehaim.net   28/09/2018
```

now we can run a for loop, find the user and set the expiration date. what I'm doing is querying the AD and asking it also the EmailAddress property, then I make a filter based on the user email, when we find the object, we pipe it to the set-ADAccountExpiration

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $UserEmail = $user.'User Email'
    Get-ADUser -Properties EmailAddress -filter "EmailAddress -eq $useremail" | Set-ADAccountExpiration -DateTime $user.'User expiration date' -Verbose
}
```

Things to consider:

1.This script depends on the assumption that you have the users email address in the EmailAddress Property

2.The date of the expiration are stored in the same format of your windows, if **not you must convert it**.

3.If the list is very big, I would recommend to first get all the users from the active directory once, and then find the users from this list, and not querying the LDAP over and over

**ALWAYS TEST BEFORE YOU GO TO PRODUCTION!!! maybe I have no idea and its all wrong ;)**

I hope I helped you even a little bit. and sorry for the bad English.

Comment: Hello, sorry for my late reply, last days were quite busy. Does your script work for you? You understood it correctly, unfortunately when I try to run the script it won't work with the error message Get-ADuser : Error parsing query: 'EmailAddress -eq'. My Csv looks exactly as you advised.

Comment: Hey, When I tried to run it, it worked with no issues.. when you import the csv, can you past your headers to here? Thanks